# Removing an element programatically from a widget

Tags: android, widget

I have an imageview and a text view in a widget layout.
Now I need to remove the image view from the remoteview programatically.

I see that there is the api **remoteView.removeAll(Viewid);**

So when I do

```
remoteViews.removeAll(R.id.imageView);
```

and update the remoteView through

```
appwidgetmanager.updateAppVidget
```

nothing concrete is visible on the screen.
the imageview is still there.

Am I on the correct track?
Kindly give your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `removeAll` is the equivalent of `ViewGroup.removeAllViews`. For it to work in a widget through a *RemoteViews* object you would need to have your `ImageView` wrapped within a `FrameLayout`. You can then call `removeAll` and pass the *id* of that `FrameLayout`.

Note that setting the visibility to *INVISIBLE* or even *GONE* is much easier with *RemoteViews*, and does not require extra `Views`.

Comment: k-ballo : How can i wrap the imageview in a framelayout ?

Comment: @Achilles: You do `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/image_frame" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"><ImageView .../></FrameLayout>` in your XML.

Comment: RemoteView rv = RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.main);          rv.removeAllViews(R.id.imageView1);
  
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(c, rv);..                  This is what i did . and the image view is not removed ?

Comment: @Achilles you cant remove all views from an imageview as it has none, but you can remove all views from the viewgroup that wraps the imageview. That is, use the id of the frame layout as an argument to the function.